# How to access JSON Object in loop using php?

Tags: php, json

I have a json object and I wanted to access it in the loop using php. Is there a way I can access it in the loop without even decoding it? Please help. Here is my code.

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($purchases); $i++){ ?>   

    <tr class="tr-purchase">

      <td>{{ $purchases[$i]['purchase_orders'] }}</td>

    </tr>
}?>
```

{"id":35,"po_code":"PMS201635","purchase_orders":"a:2:{i:0;a:7:{s:2:\"id\";s:1:\"9\";s:3:\"qty\";s:1:\"2\";s:4:\"unit\";s:7:\"Capsule\";s:6:\"pharma\";s:12:\"Ibuprofen IB\";s:9:\"packaging\";s:7:\"50 caps\";s:5:\"price\";s:2:\"23\";s:5:\"total\";s:2:\"46\";}i:1;a:7:{s:2:\"id\";s:2:\"11\";s:3:\"qty\";s:1:\"5\";s:4:\"unit\";s:6:\"Pieces\";s:6:\"pharma\";s:12:\"Ecotrin oral\";s:9:\"packaging\";s:6:\"100pcs\";s:5:\"price\";s:2:\"13\";s:5:\"total\";s:2:\"65\";}}","freight_charge":"0","overall_total":"111","created_at":"2016-05-21 16:50:49","updated_at":"2016-05-21 16:50:49","shipped_via":"Select","terms":""}

I just wanted to access some values inside the object. How can I access it? Thank you.

Comment: if it is json then use `json_decode` and access it as array.

Comment: POST you example json data, not image.

Comment: Okey what data you need as output?

Comment: In your `purchase_orders` its also another json, Specify what data you need?

Comment: I just wanted to get the "pharma\";s:12:\"Ibuprofen  and get another of the same value in the loop

Comment: okey wait for the answer.

Comment: ok. thank you so much

Comment: Check my answer and let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the example how can you got the pharma, if you need more help than please let me know. [Online Check](https://3v4l.org/XaFsK)

First you need to `json_deocde` the json string and for getting the `purchase_orders` its another serialize data, use `unserialize` and get the array again and access it.

```
$json = '{"id":35,"po_code":"PMS201635","purchase_orders":"a:2:{i:0;a:7:{s:2:\\"id\\";s:1:\\"9\\";s:3:\\"qty\\";s:1:\\"2\\";s:4:\\"unit\\";s:7:\\"Capsule\\";s:6:\\"pharma\\";s:12:\\"Ibuprofen IB\\";s:9:\\"packaging\\";s:7:\\"50 caps\\";s:5:\\"price\\";s:2:\\"23\\";s:5:\\"total\\";s:2:\\"46\\";}i:1;a:7:{s:2:\\"id\\";s:2:\\"11\\";s:3:\\"qty\\";s:1:\\"5\\";s:4:\\"unit\\";s:6:\\"Pieces\\";s:6:\\"pharma\\";s:12:\\"Ecotrin oral\\";s:9:\\"packaging\\";s:6:\\"100pcs\\";s:5:\\"price\\";s:2:\\"13\\";s:5:\\"total\\";s:2:\\"65\\";}}","freight_charge":"0","overall_total":"111","created_at":"2016-05-21 16:50:49","updated_at":"2016-05-21 16:50:49","shipped_via":"Select","terms":""}';
$result = json_decode ($json);
$arr = unserialize ($result->purchase_orders);

foreach($arr as $val){
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($val);
}
```

Specifying the value, lets cehck for the pharma is `Ibuprofen IB` or not, did this using the if condition.

```
if($val['pharma'] == 'Ibuprofen IB'){
    echo 'Yes you are in "Ibuprofen IB"';
}
```

Comment: Plus the Content of the Serialized Object is a Multidimensional Array as you can guess from its Signature...

Answer (score 2):

First you have to convert the JSON Data back into Native PHP Object by calling "json_decode($jsonData)". The Result will be a PHP Object like so:

```
    <?php
        // CREATE AN ARRAY TO HOLD THE REAL PHP OBJECT 
        // DECODED FROM THE JSON DATA
        $arrPurchases      = json_decode($purchases);
    ?>
```

Now you have all the Purchases in an array. The value of each single Key corresponds to a PHP Object which you can now access via a new Loop like so...

```
    <?php
        foreach($arrPurchases as $i=>$objPurchase){ ?>   

        <tr class="tr-purchase">
            // SINCE purchase_orders IS A SERIALIZED ARRAY
            // YOU STILL HAVE TO UNSERIALIZE IT TO GET THE DATA YOU WANT....
            // BUT YOU MAY JUST var_dump() IT TO SEE THAT YOU ARE ON TRACK...
            <?php var_dump($objPurchase->purchase_orders); ?>

            <!-- UNSERIALIZE THE DATA TO GET WHAT YOU NEED -->
            <?php $data  = unserialize($objPurchase->purchase_orders)); ?>

            <?php // RESULT OF THE UNSERIALIZE WILL BE AN ARRAY... ?>
            <?php $output = ""; foreach($data as $iDex=>$arrObj): ?>
                <td>
                    <!-- START WORKING WITH THE ARRAY: $arrObj -->
                    <!-- BUILD UP YOUR STRING OUTPUT THEREFROM & THE ECHO IT WITHIN THE <TD> -->
                    <?php //$output .= $arrObj[]; ?>
                    <?php // ECHO THE RESULTING OUTPUT HERE; ?>
                </td>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tr>

     <?php }?>
```